# Chat assíncrono em Android

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo Android onde a tela inicial pede o login de acesso do usuario. De forma simples, um usuario pode ver a lista de outros usuarios cadastrados. Preciso agora implementar um chat assíncrono. Ou seja, o usuario logado seleciona um usuario da lista e pode entao enviar uma mensagem para esses usuario (somente um texto simples). O outro usuario recebe a mensagem (pode visualizar as mensagens em um icone de seu menu) e pode responder novamente.

De que maneira posso fazer isso?

Comment: Pesquise por Google Cloud Messaging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, existem diversas maneiras de se implementar um chat no Android. Na maioria dos casos você vai precisar usar, no mínimo:

1. Uma aplicação em um servidor para hospedar e manipular os dados ( usuarios, mensagens, etc. )
2. [**G**oogle **C**loud **M**essaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) ( sistema de push notification que permite o envio e recebimento de mensagens entre aplicações Android)
3. Um app que se comunica com o seu servidor e possa receber mensagens atraves do **GCM** );

A ideia geral é a seguinte:

1. Fazer a aplicação **PHP** implementar o **GCM**, permitindo que ela possa enviar mensagens de um dispositivo Android **A** para um dispositivo Android **B** ;
2. Criar um app Android que interaja com o seu servidor;

Você pode dar uma olhada [nesse exemplo aqui](http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/instachat/) ( a implementação do servidor é em Java, mas da pra ter uma noção de como tudo funciona).